# How to use awk to prepend as string AND append the substring found after the last occurance of "/" for each line in a file

Tags: awk

I have a file myfile.sh like this:

```
tests/test1
tests/test2
tests/test3
```

I would like to do 2 things with this file:

1. prepend each line with "abc " string
2. append each line with whatever is found after the last occurrence of "/" on that line

So, my new file would need to look like:

```
abc tests/test1 test1
abc tests/test2 test2
abc tests/test3 test3
```

So far I am able to do #1 above and I am able to find the strings after the last occurrence of "/" on each line.  I am doing this on Windows using GitBash, hence I use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
awk "{print \"abc \" $0}" myfile.txt> mynewfile.txt
```

,this prepends each line with string "abc ".

```
awk -F/ "{print $NF}" myfile.txt> mynewfile.txt
```

, this finds string after the last occurrence of "/" on each line.

So, that is all good but I don't know how to do #2 to get to the desired file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk` command to print a static string as first column and using `/` as `FS` print last column:

```bash
awk -F/ 'NF {print "abc", $0, $NF}' file

abc tests/test1 test1
abc tests/test2 test2
abc tests/test3 test3
```

I have used `NF` as condition (to do it only for non-empty lines).

---

OP has to use `"` around awk command on Windows, so here it is:

```bash
# for Windows / DOS systems
awk -F/ "NF {print \"abc\", $0, $NF}" file

# for Unix based system
awk -F/ "NF {print \"abc\", \$0, \$NF}" file
```

As suggested by Ed, better to save awk script in a file and use that as awk script to avoid quotes escaping:

```
cat script.awk
NF {print "abc", $0, $NF}

awk -F/ -f script.awk file
```

Alternatively here is a `sed` command to do the same:

```bash
sed -E "s~.*/(.*)~abc & \\1~" file
```

Comment: cannot use ' on Windows

Comment: ok got it. Have provided `awk` using `"` and a `sed` as well.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you but I dont the #2 working for some reason

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, I had to modify it a bit to work.  I changed it to this `awk -F/ "NF {print \"abc\", $0, $NF}" file` (so, I had to replace escape \ in front of $0 and $NF in order to make it to work.  Mind fixing that and explaining the meening of these please?

Comment: @pixel: I have updated my answer and provided a better alternative of using awk script.